# How can I remove horizontal line under summary?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, header-footer, line-spacing, line, underline

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[pdftex, hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}

% Bitstream Charter
% \usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath} % Palatino

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% Adjust margins
%for printing \addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-7.7mm}
%for pdf \addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-12.7mm}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-12.7mm}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-12.7mm}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.6in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.0in}
%\marginparwidth=1pt


\urlstyle{same}

\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

% Sections formatting
\titleformat{\section}{
  \vspace{-6pt}\scshape\raggedright\large
}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}\titlerule \vspace{-5pt}]

%-------------------------
% Custom commands
\newcommand{\resumeItem}[2]{
  \item\small{
    \textbf{#1}{: #2 \vspace{-2pt}}
  }
}

\newcommand{\resumeItemNoBullet}[2]{
  \item[]\small{
    \hspace{-9pt}\textbf{#1}{: #2 \vspace{-6pt}}
  }
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
  \vspace{-1pt}\item[]
  \begin{tabular*}{0.98\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \hspace{-10pt}\textbf{#1} & #2 \\
      \hspace{-10pt}\text{\small#3} & \text{\small #4} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-5pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumenewSubheading}[6]{
  \vspace{-1pt}\item[]
  \begin{tabular*}{0.98\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \hspace{-10pt}\textbf{#1} & #2 \\
      \hspace{-10pt}\text{\small#3} & \text{\small #4} \\
      \hspace{-10pt}\text{\small#5} & \text{\small #6} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-5pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubItem}[2]{\resumeItem{#1}{#2}\vspace{-4pt}}

\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\circ$}

\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStart}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListEnd}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListStart}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListEnd}{\end{itemize}\vspace{-5pt}}


% custom commands
\newcommand{\shorterSection}[1]{\vspace{-10pt}\section{#1}}

%----------Summary------------------------------
\begin{document}
\vspace{3mm}
\shorterSection{\textbf{Summary}}
\vspace{0.5mm}
  I am a  --------- there.

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @DG' done that!

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: @DG' I did that too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `\titlerule` from

```
\titleformat{\section}{
  \vspace{-6pt}\scshape\raggedright\large
}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}\titlerule \vspace{-5pt}]
```

Comment: Thank you @Jose Carlos Santos