# How can remove the horizontal line in the end of overleaf template?

Tags: line-breaking, templates, overleaf

I'm working on an expose (research proposal) and I selected this [template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/uncg-phy-419-f19-proposal-template/mkzbzxjzysty) in overleaf which is 2 columns. now the problem is I want to include bibliography right after `\section{References}` but from nowhere there is horizontal line avoid that and result in losing its comprehensiveness:

```
\documentclass[%
 reprint,
%superscriptaddress,
%groupedaddress,
%unsortedaddress,
%runinaddress,
%frontmatterverbose, 
%preprint,
%preprintnumbers,
%nofootinbib,
%nobibnotes,
%bibnotes,
 amsmath,amssymb,
 aps,
%pra,
%prb,
%rmp,
%prstab,
%prstper,
%floatfix,
]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage{hyperref}% enables hyperlinks in the PDF
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\title{\small Exposé für Geschäftsidee \\ \LARGE Proposal Title}% Force line breaks with \\


\section{References}

\bibliography{bibfile}% Produces the bibliography via BibTeX.

\end{document}
```

I checked this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/538807/how-can-i-remove-horizontal-line-under-summary) but sadly wasn't my case.
So far the output is as follows:
[image: img]

I was wondering if there is an elegant way to fix it. Any helps will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this old question (I think that your question is a duplicate) [LaTeX Ugly Line Above References](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246120/latex-ugly-line-above-references), I hope to give you an answer.

```
\documentclass[%
 reprint,
%superscriptaddress,
%groupedaddress,
%unsortedaddress,
%runinaddress,
%frontmatterverbose, 
%preprint,
%preprintnumbers,
%nofootinbib,
%nobibnotes,
%bibnotes,
 amsmath,amssymb,
 aps,
%pra,
%prb,
%rmp,
%prstab,
%prstper,
%floatfix,
]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage{hyperref}% enables hyperlinks in the PDF
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\def\bibsection{\section*{\refname}}&&&&&&<---added
\begin{document}

\title{\small Exposé für Geschäftsidee \\ \LARGE Proposal Title}% Force line breaks with \\
\section{References}
\bibliography{bibfile}% Produces the bibliography via BibTeX.

\end{document}
```

The line not exist:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input. may I ask you to check my other unsolved issue below the answer of this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/557108/188245) or directly see in this [picture](https://i.imgur.com/GE9CERg.png) unknown words they appeared in profile biography

Comment: @Mario I understood that you want to have an answer....but I'm not very good user :-(..my many problems are to understand the questions...:-( sorry. Do you can wait to have other answers? I hope to yes.

Comment: sure man. Sorry for inconvenience since I felt that you know these ugly unwanted problems I asked for. on the other hand I need to submit the research proposal and I'm in a hurry. Thanks again. I mark the answer to this post. in case you understand where are coming from these words plz feel free to share your answer.

Comment: @Mario Welcome for me....and for the kind user like you. :-)...My problems are also to understand the request of the user and I see often the picture to know the reason. I'm not very good also with english language...It has known by many user into community of TeX.SE.

Comment: I do like your cool post about [Super Mario](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510748/drawing-super-mario-bros-in-latex). Good job! It's clear you're a scientific as your profile says.

Comment: @Mario Ahahahah...I'm a scarce scientific user...aahahha.